# Why search performance is difference between from&size and search&after

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

There are hundreds of millions of documents in my index. When I search, I find that search&after is much slower than from&size。 Use from&size，search is quick，took several ms return，but use search after，it took 20 seconds。My search result is sort by time and key(a keyword copy of _id) ，Why？what's the difference?
search cmd:

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {
                    "query_string":{
                        "query":"*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range":{
                        "__time__":{
                            "gte":1324958207,
                            "lte":1724958207
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size":10,
    "sort":[
        {
            "__time__":{
                "order":"desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "__key__":{
                "order":"desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "search_after":[
        1630594662000,
        "6130e666-2-67e9e3-f5-1"
    ],
    "profile":true
}
```

profile:

```
{"searches":[
                    {
                        "query":[
                            {
                                "type":"BoostQuery",
                                "description":"(ConstantScore(DocValuesFieldExistsQuery [field=__time__]))^0.0",
                                "time_in_nanos":45722536283,
                                "breakdown":{
                                    "set_min_competitive_score_count":0,
                                    "match_count":0,
                                    "shallow_advance_count":0,
                                    "set_min_competitive_score":0,
                                    "next_doc":45722241414,
                                    "match":0,
                                    "next_doc_count":410919487,
                                    "score_count":0,
                                    "compute_max_score_count":0,
                                    "compute_max_score":0,
                                    "advance":19517,
                                    "advance_count":39,
                                    "score":0,
                                    "build_scorer_count":78,
                                    "create_weight":14271,
                                    "shallow_advance":0,
                                    "create_weight_count":1,
                                    "build_scorer":261081
                                },
                                "children":[
                                    {
                                        "type":"DocValuesFieldExistsQuery",
                                        "description":"DocValuesFieldExistsQuery [field=__time__]",
                                        "time_in_nanos":16571715415,
                                        "breakdown":{
                                            "set_min_competitive_score_count":0,
                                            "match_count":0,
                                            "shallow_advance_count":0,
                                            "set_min_competitive_score":0,
                                            "next_doc":16571493898,
                                            "match":0,
                                            "next_doc_count":410919487,
                                            "score_count":0,
                                            "compute_max_score_count":0,
                                            "compute_max_score":0,
                                            "advance":15074,
                                            "advance_count":39,
                                            "score":0,
                                            "build_scorer_count":78,
                                            "create_weight":517,
                                            "shallow_advance":0,
                                            "create_weight_count":1,
                                            "build_scorer":205926
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "rewrite_time":116538,
                        "collector":[
                            {
                                "name":"PagingFieldCollector",
                                "reason":"search_top_hits",
                                "time_in_nanos":30851166561
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "aggregations":[

                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `search_after` use `scroll` approach for filtering which supposed to sort all the data before filtering, instead of `from/size` which only retrieved elements as a stream, and will be slower and hit memory as much as you go deeper with a `from`

Comment: But in my test, search after is 10x slower than from size, offset of both  is zero.

Comment: Yes that's logic, like said, you have one which will need a global view, and the other that is just a stream of the top response